# ASP.NET MVC Generic Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Is is possible to have a partial view inherit more than one model? I have three models (Contacts, Clients, Vendors) that all have address information (Address). In the interest of being DRY I pulled the address info into it's own model, Addresses. I created a partial create / update view of addresses and what to render this in other other three model's create / update views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a composite view model, you can still be DRY and have three views (Contacts, Clients, Vendors). If you are concerned about repeating yourself when displaying the address information just make a display template for the type. That way you can write out all the specific information for each Contact, Client, and Vendor in their own views and just drop in:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Address) %>
```

Now you are being DRY while still supporting the Single Responsibility Principle.

For more on Display and Edit templates you can look at [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) or [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx) posts on it.

Comment: Isn't `Html.DisplayFor()` an ASP.NET MVC 2 feature?

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a new model that contains all three models (Contacts, Clients, Vendors) . Then pass this new model to your partial. From there you can have access to all three models from your newly created model.

Comment: I don't think he needs to render them all at the same time.  He created a view that's used to render an address, and now wants to make a call to render that from inside the Contacts/Clients/Vendors views.

Comment: I initially had all three models in one, but their information was unique enough that it made sense to separate them. I do agree that this would be easier though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is with a composite view model (which is not necessarily a bad thing), so something like:

```
public class MyControllerActionViewModel
{
    public IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public IList<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public IList<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
}
```

We use this approach a lot to get more elements into the view when needed, and I see no bad practice in using these custom view models whenever needed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: only alpha males unfortunately ;)

Comment: doesn't matter since neither one of you gave the right answer

Comment: @R0MANARMY - Nobody asked your opinion.

Comment: @gmcalab: It's not an opinion, it's a fact.  I didn't mean it in a "you didn't give the accepted answer" way.  I meant it in a "you misunderstood the question and gave a completely irrelevant (and incorrect) answer."

Comment: @R0MANARMY - oh really, is that how you see it? I'm glad you think you're some sort of authority on here.